# jq: Recursively rename keys

Tags: jq

I have JSON with structure like what's shown below. "groups" may be nested under "items" to any arbitrary depth, so I need to write an expression that visits every "groups" and "items" property (or parent object); static paths won't do.

```
{
    "groups": [{
        "name": "group1",
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "item1",
                "groups": [
                    {
                        "name": "nestedGroup1",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "name": "nestedItem1",
                                "groups": []
                            },{
                                "name": "nestedItem2",
                                "groups": []
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "item2",
                "groups": []
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

How can I recursively rename all "groups" to say "newGroups" and "items" to "newItems"? If you break it down, I know I need to create new keys at each level and delete the old ones, but I'm having trouble expressing that. I've tried several variations on things like

```
.. |= if type == "object" and has("groups") then . + { newGroups: .groups } else . end
```

to perform the first step, but this results in copying the top-level "groups" value to "newGroups" while leaving the nested "groups" unchanged. The remaining values within "groups" then also get sibling "newGroups" with their nested "groups" with no "newGroups" siblings etc.

From observation, my understanding is that the paths generated by the `..` operator are evaluated first, so the newly added key is never traversed. So then I tried variations on the above, replacing `..` with `recurse` both with and without arguments, thinking that it would take the value produced by the RHS and feed it back in to the LHS, like this:

```
{ newGroups: .groups } | recurse |= if type == "object" and has("groups") then . + { newGroups: .groups } elif type == "object" and has("items") then . + { newItems: .items } else . end
```

The result is closer, but still so far away. The recursion kind of works, but only on keys that already existed; the new ones appended to the object are not visited.

I've also tried messing about with `paths`, `getpath`, and `setpath` to try to solve the problem that way but run into problems there as well. Please help me get unstuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very well explained in [jq - FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#frequently-asked-questions) under recursive traversal using `walk/1`. I've used a standard implementation of `walk/1` from [jq-builtins](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq) page, since the version I have doesn't have it present by default.

From the documentation for `walk/1` - recursively walks the input JSON entity, changing each encountered key, `k`, to `(k|filter)`, where `filter` is the specified filter, which may be any `jq` expression.

I've used the following filter in my script

```
# Apply f to composite entities recursively, and to atoms
def walk(f):
  . as $in
  | if type == "object" then
      reduce keys_unsorted[] as $key
        ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
  elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
  else f
  end;

def translate_keys(f):
  walk( if type == "object" then
            with_entries( if .key | contains("groups") then
                             .key |= "newgroups"
                          elif .key | contains("items") then
                             .key |= "newitems"
                          else
                             . end
                        )
        else
            . end
      );


translate_keys(.)
```

and ran the script as

```
jq -f script.jq json
```

which produced the result you needed.

Comment: Why is this downvoted now? Would appreciate a reason for the same

Answer (score -1):

If the problem requires that "items" only be renamed in a subtree under a "groups" key, then a walk within a walk would be called for:

```
walk(if type == "object" and has("groups")
     then .newGroups = .groups | del(.groups)
     | walk(if type == "object" and has("items")
            then .newItems = .items | del(.items)
            else . end)
     else . end)
```